# How do I correctly add key input to a sprite image across multiple files?

Tags: python, pygame

I have created this to move a sprite. I set a sprite images cordinates to (spritex, 300) in a diffrent file. When  run the program and press the right or left arrow, there is no movement. The value of spritex changes, in a print function

I have checked that the program is reading the key press's by adding a print function. Am I setting up the program wrong?

---

------Movement Function File

```
import pygame
import os, sys
from itertools import *
from oryxsprites import *
from oryxdisplay import *
spritex = 300
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 640))

def movementsprite():   

    global spritex

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             running = False

    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
              spritex += 10
              print spritex

    elif keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:              
              spritex -= 10
              print spritex
```

---

------Display Function file---------------

```
import pygame
import itertools
from oryxsprites import *
from McharMovement import *
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 640))
spritex = 300
def backgroundmain():
    movementsprite()

    backdrop = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 640, 640) 
    screen.fill((50,50,50))
    playingfeildwidth = (32, 608)
    playingfeildheight = (32, 608)

screen.blit(warrior1, (spritex, 320))

pygame.display.flip()
```

--------Main File------------------

```
import pygame
import os, sys
from itertools import *
from oryxsprites import *
from oryxdisplay import *
from McharMovement import *
running = True

while running:

    backgroundmain()
    pygame.display.set_caption('OryxGame')
    pygame.display.set_icon(grasstile)


    for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             running = False
             pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Is that where you're first assigning spritex? Because if so, the error  probably means that you have to move the 'spritex = 100' line to the other file before you call this one and also before you try and "set image coordinates to (spritex, 300)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
spritex = 100

def movementsprite():
    global spritex  #I added this line
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             running = False

    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
              spritex += 10
              print spritex

    elif keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:              
              spritex -= 10
```

That should work fine

If the sprite is still not moving, then the problem is now when you call your function to move it. How are you moving it? You need to call that movement function from inside `def movementsprite():`

And if you want to call the movement function from another file, use

`from other_file import movement_func`

or even

`from other_file import *`

UPDATE:
Just add a return statement to your movement function, `return spritex`

Then in the Display function, when you call the movement function change the line to 
`spritex=movementfunction()`

That will alter the value of spritex between the files. And you dont have to make spritex global at the top of your movement function.

Hope I could help! :)

Comment: So if I do add this, I receive no errors. I know spritex is being changed when a key is pressed due to the print function. The problem is that the sprite does not move and stays at the initial value of spritex. @hammythepig

Comment: @enrique2334 in that case the problem is now when you call your function to move it.  How are you moving it? You need to call that movement function from inside `def movementsprite():`

Comment: So I moved the movement function to the same file as the sprite is displayed and it worked correctly. Is there a way I can have the movement function in a different file than the display file/function. @hammythepig

Comment: @enrique2334 I would just import the function. so `from other_file import movement_func` or even `from other_file import *`

Comment: that's what I have been trying to do. I cant get the sprite to move if the movement func is in a separate file as the display func. any suggestions. @hammythepig

Comment: @enrique2334 Hmmm thats strange, I have some things that use other functions in different files that work. Maybe it's your movement function, can I see that?

Comment: I added the three files that are used. @hammythepig

Comment: Thank you, I would have never figured that out. I think thats the second answer you've given me.

Answer (score 0):

Your `spritex` variable is out of scope from the looks of it. You need to make it available to the `movementsprite()` function.

Putting `global` infront of your variable declaration may solve this